# Is there is a way to keep my modal open in Laravel after submit and save the values to db?

Tags: ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I am uploading a file in  **Laravel 8** with having one bootstrap modal which works dynamically . everything is working fine but I want to improve my output more:
**1) Update one of my forms through a modal without refreshing the page?
2) keep the modal open if the validation fails and print the errors to modal instead of my redirect page?**

I will appreciate your time helping me.

> my form for updating the file

```
<form action="{{ route('storefile' , $requisition->id) }}" method="POST"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
@method('PUT')
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <label for="title"> Account Status: </label>
    <select class="form-control" name="acc_status">
        <option value="0" {{ $requisition->acc_status == 0 ? 'selected' : '' }}> Inactive
        </option>
        <option value="1" {{ $requisition->acc_status == 1     ? 'selected' : '' }}> Active
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 pt-4">
    <label for="title"> Account document File: </label>
    <div>
        @if (!empty($requisition->acc_document))
        <label class="badge-success">
            {{ $requisition->acc_document }}
        </label>
        @else
        <label class="badge-danger">
            Nothing uploaded </label>
        @endif
    </div>
    <input type="file" name="acc_document" class="form-control" id="acc_document" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="card-footer">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload document" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

> my controller and route

```
public function uploadFile($id) {
$requisition = Requisition::find($id);
return view('requisition.createFile' , compact('requisition'));

}

public function storeFile(Request $request , $id) {

$request->validate([
    'acc_status'            => 'required',
    'acc_document'          => 'required|mimes:doc,docx,pdf,txt,zip|max:2000',
]);
    $requisition = Requisition::find($id);
    $requisition->acc_status =  $request->get('acc_status');
    $FileName = uniqid() .$request->file('acc_document')->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $request->file('acc_document')->storeAs('uploads', $FileName , 'public');
    $requisition->acc_document = '/storage/' . $path;
    }
    $requisition->save();
    //$requisition->update($request->all());

return back()
    ->with('success', 'Your file has been uploaded successfully.');
}
```

`Route::get('upload/{id}', [RequisitionController::class, 'uploadFile'])->name('upload');`
`Route::put('requisition/{id}/files', [RequisitionController::class, 'storeFile'])->name('storefile');`

> and last part my modal and ajax in my index page to upload the file and popup will open

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<a style="display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; margin-right:10px;"
    class="text-secondary" data-toggle="modal" id="mediumButton"
    data-target="#mediumModal" title="upload"
    data-attr="{{ route('upload' , $requisition->id)  }}">
    <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
</a>
</div>
```

```
<script>
// display a modal (medium modal)
$(document).on('click', '#mediumButton', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let href = $(this).attr('data-attr');
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loader').show();
        },
        // return the result
        success: function(result) {
            //  @if (count($errors) > 0) @endif
            $('#mediumModal').modal("show");
            $('#mediumBody').html(result).show();
            $("#date-picker").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
        } ,
        complete: function() {
            $('#loader').hide();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, testStatus, error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert("Page " + href + " cannot open. Error:" + error);
            $('#loader').hide();
        },
        timeout: 8000
    });

});
</script>
```

```
<!-- medium modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="mediumModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mediumModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" id="mediumBody">
                <form id="modal-form" method="get">
                    <div>
                        <!-- the result of displayed apply here -->
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**what I want to implement looks like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21I00.gif)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this kind of thing. One way to do it, is to do something like this:

Html:

```
<div class="modal" id="the-modal">
    <form action="{{ $theAction }}" method="POST" id="the-form">
        <input type="text" name="input-name" id="the-input">
        <button type="submit">
    </form>
    <p id="the-text"></p>
</div>
```

In your Controller you will return an error or an 200 response, if everything is ok.

```
public function theAction(Request $request , $id) {
    //Do stuff

    if (!$error) {
        return response("OK"); //This will return a 200 response
    } else {
        return response("An error happened", 500); //This will return a 500 error
    }
}
```

Then, in your JS, you'll intercept form submission and then, you're going to be able to separate errors from ok messages:

```
<script>
$("#the-form").on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let theInput = $("#the-input");
    $.ajax({
        url: theUrl,
        data: {
            the-input: theInput
        }
        // 200 response
        success: function(result) {
            $("#the-text").empty();
            $("#the-text").append(result.repsonse);
        } ,
        error: function(jqXHR, testStatus, error) {
            $("#the-text").empty();
            $("#the-text").append(error.response);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

If you want to do all this stuff inside a modal, the concept is just the same: You intercept form submission, send to controller, return separate responses for errors and 200 responses, and then update manually the inputs/texts.

I did't test the code, but the concept should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I were able to do it by some helps from Laracast and your concept, since you are the only one to help me here you deserve an acceptation for your answer.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you my friend! :)